# css for display map in div tag

Tags: html, css

I want to place the map between address and contact us form.Now map is displayed
above the contact form. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lc965o5d/)

[image]

I want to display map 'm' between address 'A' and contact form 'c'.

```css
@charset "utf-8";
 body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: #82CAFA;
  font: normal 12px/1.5em"Liberation sans", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: #f3f3f3 url(../images/) repeat-x center top;
  background-color: #E3F2FF;
}
html,
.main {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.main {
  background: url(../images/header_bg.jpg) no-repeat center top;
}
.clr {
  clear: both;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}
h2 {
  margin: 8px 0;
  padding: 8px 0;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #343537;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #c8c8c8;
}
p {
  margin: 8px 0;
  padding: 0 0 8px 0;
}
a {
  color: #3183bf;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.header,
.content,
.menu_nav,
.fbg,
.footer,
form,
ol,
ol li,
ul,
.content .mainbar,
.content .sidebar {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.header {} .header_resize {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 960px;
}
.logo {
  padding: 0 0 0 20px;
  float: none;
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  height: 104px;
}
h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 24px 0 0;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  text-transform: none;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
h1 a,
h1 a:hover {
  color: #efeeee;
  text-decoration: none;
}
h1 span {} h1 small {
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  color: #efeeee;
}
.menu_nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 11px 0 0 24px;
  height: 45px;
}
.menu_nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
}
.menu_nav ul li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 7px;
  2px 0 0;
  float: left;
  background: url(../images/split.gif) no-repeat right center;
}
.menu_nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 7px 24px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 19px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}
.menu_nav ul li.active a,
.menu_nav ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}
.slider {
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #fff;
}
.content {
  padding: 0px;
}
.content_resize {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 24px 0 40px;
  width: 960px;
}
.content .mainbar {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: right;
  width: 300px;
}
.content .mainbar h2 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  color: #212121;
}
.content .mainbar div.img {
  padding: 0 0 12px;
  float: left;
}
.content .mainbar img {} .content .mainbar img.fl {
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid #dedede;
}
.content .mainbar .article {
  margin: 0 0 80px;
  padding: 6px 20px;
}
.content .mainbar .post_content {} .content .mainbar .post_content strong {
  color: #6d6d6d;
}
.content .sidebar {
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  width: 260px;
}
.content .sidebar .gadget {
  margin: 0 0 12px;
  padding: 6px 20px 24px;
}
.content .sidebar h2 {
  color: #212121;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">

  <div class="content_resize">

    <div class="mainbar">
      <div id="map-canvas" style="width:500px;height:350px;border:1px solid black;"></div>
      <div class="demo">

        <h3 style="color:black;">Contuct Us</h3>
        <form method="POST" autocomplete="off">
          <div>
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="NAME" required>
          </div>
          <br>
          <div>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-MAIL" onblur="javascript:myFunction(this.value);" required>
          </div>
          <br>
          <div><span id="error" style="color: Red; display: none"></span>
            <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="phone" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;">
          </div>
          <br>
          <div>
            <textarea name="message" placeholder="MESSAGE" required></textarea>
          </div>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <div>
            <input type="submit" name="send" value="SEND">
          </div>
        </form>

        <div class="clr"></div>

        <div class="post_content">



        </div>
        <div class="clr"></div>

      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">
      <div class="demo">
        <h4 class="star"><span>sample</span>Technologies</h4>
        <div class="clr"></div>
        <p>
          No 242, VR STREET,
          <br>address,
          <br>address1,
          <br>area,
          <br>sample.
          <br>
          <br>info@sample.com


          <br>Tel: 9995432702,9942564712
          <br>
        </p>

      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="clr"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Float div a to left and div c to right, if your width of all divs are not greater than body with it will adjust the map div to center. For better appearance you might have to add some margin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change order of your elements in DOM to this:

```
<div>
    <div class="sidebar"></div>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    <div class="mainbar"></div>
</div>
```

And also apply this css:

```
.content_resize {
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:24px 0 40px;
    width:1092px; //260 + 500 +(2px borders) + 300
}

.sidebar, .mainbar, #map-canvas {
    float: left;
}
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lhj8hrby/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can float all three divs left and place them in order of A->M->C, just making sure they don't extend past the width of the page.

```
.a { float: left; }
```